# rename() not working Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rename

I have a Wordpress plugin that will take the name of one directory on the server and rename to a name set in a Settings/Options field. The code I'm using is:

```
$base = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$path = (isset($xgeneral['obf_plugin']))
    ?$xgeneral['obf_plugin']
    :'original_directory';

if ($path != $base) {

    $former = $base . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mig_plugin.php';
    $newer = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mig_plugin.php';
    rename($former,$newer);
}
```

So what happens is when the plugin loads the first time, it checks if the `obf_plugin` option is the same as the directory in question; if they are different, it then renames it.

However, no matter what I try I get the error `rename(migratex/mig_plugin.php,tango/mig_plugin.php): no such file or directory` (tango is just the dumb sample word I tried to use) I tried referencing the absolute file path on the server using this code:

```
define("DS","/",true);
define('BASE_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS,true);
```

but that doesn't make a difference.

Is there any reason why the `rename()` function is not working? It is running inside the Wordpress Admin page.

Thank you!

EDIT: Further investigation reveals this works in plain PHP but **will not when running in Wordpress**. Any thoughts as to how to enable rename() in Wordpress?

Comment: Why is this not in an action hook?

Comment: It is; I called it using admin_init.

Comment: @RalphTheWonderLlama "Further investigation reveals this works in plain PHP but will not when running in Wordpress." Did you learn any more about this? I have a similar issue - unable to programmatically move the [original_image]-size media item from one folder to another, but all other sizes move just fine from/to same folder; file permissions are the same. Anything to do with locks?